# Xamarin iOS to MAUI .net8

Tags: xamarin.ios, maui

i'm trying to convert my Xamarin iOS project to MAUI .net8. But after convert with upgrade done, i have error that UIView using in Xamarin.ios was missing, but cannot install xamarin.ios anymore. Anybody can help me with this? Thank you

I have search for a lot of time but don't find any question or document relate to this

Comment: For migration from Xamarin Native projects, you could refer to [Upgrade Xamarin native projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: Yes, i already refer to it, i use auto update of VS2022, but when done the update, the UIView and UIViewController throw many error but i can't find anything to alter them.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include how to reproduce this issue?